# Regex length constraint

Tags: regex, pcre

This is my current regex.
(Needs at least one alphabet, number and special character. Length between 8 to 100)

```
^(?=.*([a-zA-Z]))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+{8,100}$
```

I want to prevent string that starts with or end with space.
To do that, I tried

```
^(?=.*([a-zA-Z]))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w]))[^\s].+[^\s]{8,100}$
```

But the `{8, 100}` only applied to last `[^\s]`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: With more optimization: [`/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^\W_]*[\W_])\S.{6,98}\S$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/gf0QkI/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of matching `.+{8,100}` (which isn't valid regex syntax), match a non-space, followed by 6 to 98 characters, followed by another non-space. You can use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`, and similarly, `\W` instead of `[^\w]`:

```
^(?=.*([a-zA-Z]))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(?:_|\W))\S.{6,98}\S$
                               ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```